# RFC822-style sources.list yields "E: Type 'Types:' is not known"

Tags: debian, apt

On Jessie, according to `man 5 sources.list`, I can write my `sources.list` file in an RFC822-inspired format:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://http.us.debian.org/debian/
Suites: jessie
Sections: main contrib non-free
```

Unfortunately, that yields an error:

```
root@Zia:~# apt-get update
E: Type 'Types:' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Why doesn't the documented RFC822 format work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reviewing the [apt changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/a/apt/apt_1.0.9.8_changelog) finds this entry under 0.9.14.3~exp5:

> - set `APT::Sources::Use-Deb822=false` until the format is fully finalized *[formatting added]*

so it appears they just forgot to document in the manual page that there is an option to turn support on or off and further it's disabled by default. The documentation problem is already reported as [bug 736710](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736710).

To make it work, add `APT::Sources::Use-Deb822 true;` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (or a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`).

## Update 2015-11-25

Experimental apt no longer users the above option. Instead, you must put deb822-style sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` under a file name matching `*.sources` (traditional-style ones go under `*.list`). Also, `Sections:` has been renamed `Components:`.